# How can I draw an image to a canvas in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I'm struggling to draw a simple image on a canvas in GWT.  Here is my program:

```
public class BlahTest implements EntryPoint {

    private final Images images = GWT.create(Images.class);

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
        Context2d ctx = canvas.getContext2d();
        ctx.setFillStyle("blue");
        ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 30, 30);
        Image img = new Image(images.pencil());
        ImageElement imgEl = ImageElement.as(img.getElement());
        canvas.getContext2d().drawImage(imgEl, 50, 50);

        RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
        rp.add(canvas);

    }
}
```

The Images interface looks like this, with the Pencil.png in the same folder:

```
public interface Images extends ClientBundle {
    @Source("Pencil.png")
    ImageResource pencil();

}
```

The image is simply not drawn.  I've also tried waiting for the image to load with img.addLoadHandler() but still it is not drawn....

Any suggestions?

EDIT: As Aki pointed out, this seems to have been due to a bug which has been fixed in version 2.6 of GWT

Comment: maybe this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7403.

Comment: Aki you are right - I downloaded the new version of GWT (2.6) and it works fine now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You almost there. just replace this

> Image img = new Image(images.pencil());

with

> Image img = new Image(images.pencil().getSafeUri());